# extracting values from awk array in one line

Tags: awk

I have an array like this ,for each package it hold of count of fail ,testcount,error. or each package i want to extract the values of fail , test count and error and print in one line

```
test_result["012_project_y2014","fails"] = 1;     
test_result["012_project_y2014","testcount"] =3;    
test_result["012_project_y2014", "error"] = 1;  

test_result["012_project_y2013","fails"] = 0;             
test_result["012_project_y2013","testcount"]=1;    
test_result["012_project_y2013", "error"] = 1;  




    for (y in test_result){

            split(y,sep1,SUBSEP);



            pkg = sep1[1];

            result =  sep1[2];

            if (result == "testcase")
            {
                    ptest = test_result[sep1[1],sep1[2]];
            }
            if (result == "fail")
            {
                    pfail = test_result[sep1[1],sep1[2]];
            }
            if(result == "error")
            {
                    perror = test_result[sep1[1],sep1[2]];
            }
            count = test_result[sep1[1],sep1[2]];


            print "<testsuite errors=\42"perror"\42"" " "failures=\42"pfail"\42"" " "hostname=\42localhost\42  id=\"0\42  name=\42"pkg"\42"" ""package=\42"pkg"\42"" " "tests=\42"ptest"\42"" " "timestamp=\42"date"\42"">\n";
```

}

the output which i am getting is as below where it prints the testsuite for each each count  ie fail , test count , error it prints one line

```
<testsuite errors="" failures="" hostname="localhost"  id="0"  
name="012_project_y2014 " package="012_project_y2014 " tests="1" 
timestamp="">  


<testsuite errors="" failures="0" hostname="localhost"  id="0"  
name="012_project_y2014 " package="012_project_y2014 " tests="1" 
timestamp="">  


<testsuite errors="" failures="1" hostname="localhost"  id="0"  
name="012_project_y2013 " package="012_project_y2013 " tests="1" 
timestamp="">  


<testsuite errors="1" failures="1" hostname="localhost"  id="0"  
name="012_project_y2014 " package="012_project_y2014 " tests="1" 
timestamp="">  

<testsuite errors="1" failures="1" hostname="localhost"  id="0"  
name="012_project_y2013 " package="012_project_y2013 " tests="3" 
timestamp="">  

<testsuite errors="1" failures="1" hostname="localhost"  id="0" 
name="012_project_y2013 " package="012_project_y2013 " tests="3" 
timestamp="">
```

the expected output is as below where i can access all the fail , testscase, error  of package in one line and print

```
    <testsuite errors="" failures="1" hostname="localhost"  id="0"  name="012_project_y2013 " package="012_project_y2013 " tests="1" timestamp="">

    <testsuite errors="1" failures="1" hostname="localhost"  id="0"  name="012_project_y2013 " package="012_project_y2013 " tests="3" timestamp="">
```

or is there a way i can handle this array in a different way where i can get the expected result . i think of a lot nothing worked the above one is getting close for my result but printing 3 lines where i need the results in one line.
any help is appreciated

Comment: Please post sample Input and expected output on your post in CODE TAGS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would be better off separating the conditions into their own arrays, but lacking that you can have a more systematic approach

```
test_result["012_project_y2014","fails"] = 1;     
test_result["012_project_y2014","testcount"] = 3;    
test_result["012_project_y2014","error"] = 1;  

test_result["012_project_y2013","fails"] = 0;             
test_result["012_project_y2013","testcount"] = 1;    
test_result["012_project_y2013","error"] = 1;  

for (y in test_result) {
  split(y,ss,SUBSEP);
  names[ss[1]]; status[ss[2]];
}

for(n in names) {
  printf "name=%s", n;
  for(s in status) printf "%s=%s", OFS s, test_result[n,s];
  print "";
}
...
```

will give you

```
name=012_project_y2013 fails=0 error=1 testcount=1
name=012_project_y2014 fails=1 error=1 testcount=3
```

you can further format the result as your needs...